# Deep Linking with Android app using MailChimp

Tags: android, mailchimp, deep-linking

I am just curious to know the possibility of the below scenario,

I have a MailChimp URL with the product page,( Say http://www.androidapp.com/productpage?product_id=10 ) Now this url is sent to user email. Whenever user clicks on the url, the android app should gets open the particular product screen in the installed app. Is this achievable?

I had analyzed with these references and yet to find the possibility of achieving it.
Refered: 
https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_deep_linking
[Dynamic Link Actions in mailchimp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392981/dynamic-link-actions-in-mailchimp)

Comment: Maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392981/dynamic-link-actions-in-mailchimp/39632830#39632830